How to find the maximum value of $\sin(x) \times (1+\cos(x))$ without calculus?
How to find the maximum value of
$$
\sin\left(x\right)
\left[1 + \cos\left(x\right)\right]
$$
without using calculus ?. If possible, how to do it ?.
\begin{align*}
\mbox{Assume}\ y & = \sin\left(x\right)\left[1 + \cos\left(x\right)\right],
\\[1mm] \mbox{then}\ y^{2} & = \left[1 + \cos\left(x\right)\right]^{3}\left[1 − \cos\left(x\right)\right]
\end{align*}
I can solve this with calculus, but how to do without it ?.

Welcome to Math Stack Exchange! Please share the context of the question, add your attempts since this is not a homework answering site. This site encourages your active participation in the problems you're facing.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Yes, Sir.  Assume $, y=\sin(x)(1+\cos(x)), then , y^2=(1+\cos(x))^3(1-\cos(x)) $
I can solve this with calculus, but how to do without it?

As Gary says, context should be added by editing, not just as a comment - I've edited your comment into the question.

You should improve your latex.

@BobDobbs You are right. Is there a latex guide?

Yes there is. Google "Math jax" words. @CliveZhao

And why are there * s or $\times$ for products? And why are parentheses needed in $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$?

That's what I want to know. The syntax is easy to find. But should I use \cdot or \times or just * or space? Is there a guide line but not the syntax? I am just a high school level, I don't know much about the latex world. Thanks a lot.

Just delete $*$s and $\times$ s and some parentheses. You don't need latex to delete. Back space button does. @CliveZhao

From the comment, you say you have already gotten to $y^2=(1+\cos x)^3(1-\cos x)$. You can maximise this without calculus by applying the AM-GM inequality to $\frac{1+\cos x}{3},\frac{1+\cos x}{3},\frac{1+\cos x}{3},1-\cos x$, to get
$$\frac{(1+\cos x)^3(1-\cos x)}{27}\leq \frac 1{16},$$
so $|y|\leq \frac{3\sqrt 3}4$. You get $y=\frac{3\sqrt 3}4$ for $x=\frac{\pi}{3}$, so this is indeed the maximum.

You are a hero to me. Thanks.

@CliveZhao Come on, you showed the way. Did you write the components of AM-GM accidentaly?

@BobDobbs I originally aimed to solve the problem using calculus, which led me to find a polynomial for a trigonometric function—and along the way, I accidentally triggered the AM-GM inequality.

@CliveZhao You may accept this answer. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

$$\sin x(1+\cos x)=4\sin\dfrac x2\cos^3\dfrac x2$$
Now for the maximum value, both multiplicand should have the same sign.
WLOG assuming both $>0$ and using AM-GM inequality and utilizing  $\sin^2\dfrac x2+\cos^2\dfrac x2=1$ with $a>0,$
$$\dfrac{\left(\sin\dfrac x2\right)^2+a\cdot\dfrac{\left(\cos\dfrac x2\right)^2}a}{1+a}\ge\sqrt[a+1]{\sin^2\dfrac x2\left(\dfrac{\cos^2\dfrac x2}a\right)^a}$$
$$\implies\dfrac1{a+1}\ge\dfrac{\left(\sin\dfrac x2\right)^{\dfrac2{a+1}}\left(\cos\dfrac x2\right)^{\dfrac{2a}{a+1}}}{(a)^{\dfrac a{a+1}}}$$
the equality occurs if $\sin^2\dfrac x2=\dfrac{\cos^2\dfrac x2}a\iff\cot^2\dfrac x2=a$
Comparing with the exponents of $\cos\dfrac x2, \sin\dfrac x2$
$$\dfrac31=\dfrac{\dfrac{2a}{a+1}}{\dfrac2{a+1}}\implies a=3$$
$$\implies\dfrac14\ge\dfrac{\left(\sin\dfrac x2\right)^{\dfrac12}\left(\cos\dfrac x2\right)^{\dfrac32}}{3^{\frac 34}}$$
Take square in both sides.
